# React import from wrong directory

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I click on useState, I get wrong import:

```
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.development";
```

I need to click and get:

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

[image: Import is wrong]

How to change this?

package.json
[image]

Comment: Do you build your react app with typescript?

Comment: No. I just run `npx create-react-app my-app`, and this is a problem. The same thing happens with other hooks.

Comment: Would you show me package.json in ur project?

Comment: Go to vs code preferences, settings. Search for import module specifier. It should be set to shortest, what do you have?

Comment: I found no wrong set up in ur file. You should follow SamiEIK's advise! Maybe some wrong set up about auto completion affectes your workplace

Comment: I have shortest.

Comment: it sometimes happens with me but i don't care so much about it

Comment: You have shortest but do you see: (Modified in: Workspace) written above? Does your issue only happen in this project or every project? Could you add a screenshot of your import preferences in VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same problem. It suddenly happened few days ago to me, don't know what exactly gone wrong with my project.

But, I found temporary solution and using it.

install `@types/react` into your project.

solution from: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141385